# What is the progress in the field of distributing mobile device computations across different devices or clouds?

Tags: android, cloud, distributed-computing, mobile-phones

I would like to know if it is worth expending time on distributing some processable entity in mobile devices(such as assembly instruction or machine level instruction) across multiple devices in the networking vicinity formed by an ad-hoc network or even a properly established network. This is considering that we are not a part of a company or do not have access to very advanced facilities. Our preferred target are Andorid OS based devices.

I've come across the following links and would like to know if anybody has any idea about the level to which this field has progressed.

http://www.intel.com/pressroom/kits/innovation/newsletter/eNewsJune/Q2articles/article4.html
http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/

So why aren't we seeing much in common usage?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is (as mostly in this systems) the coordination, it is much easier to have a centralised server or cluster which would coordinate all the actions - for this there are already apps which leverage the power of a smartphone to compute scientific tasks

- [BIONIC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.berkeley.boinc)
- [Samsung Power Sleep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.samsung.powersleep&hl=en)

On the other hand, many big companies allow to use the smartphone only as a display device while most of the computation is done on the server.

Both aspects involve a central server. If we look at p2p in general, it is mostly used for data and messaging transfer (BitTorrent, original version of Skype, Spotify, ...) for not time critical scenarios.

I don't know of any MMORPG or similar which would be deployed on top of a decentralised p2p system, even in an adhoc network. Once something like this will exist for PCs, it shouldn't be far from an implementation for mobile devices as well.

However even than you wouldn't "simply" split assembly instructions but rather pass messages with small data chunks around (MPI, Message Queue-services).

As for cloudsim, it is only a simulation software, where you can define parameters of your distribute program, devices and network, and it will calculate how long the calculation will take.